# Why does Math.round(1.53*20)/20 = 1.55? How does this actually work?

Tags: javascript, math

This is more of a theoretical question but why does this snippet round up to the nearest 0.05?

```
Math.round(1.53*20)/20
```

Math.round(1.53) is 2. Math.round(1.53)/20 is 0.1  Then

```
Math.round(1.53*20)/20
```

is magically **1.55**. Is there a more mathemagical way to understand this?

Comment: Do you mean `Math.round(1.53*20)/20`? This would give the result `1.55` but the expression you give would not.

Comment: `Math.round(1.53/20)/20` gives me 0. Where do you get 1.55?

Comment: your code returns (expected) **`0`**.

Comment: `Math.round(1.53/20)/20;` gives `0` not `1.55`

Comment: Even though you question is not clear... the reason for javascript rounding issues is because javascript numbers are binary floating-point representations which can only approximate many decimal fractions. You can find a more accurate way to round with [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158781/rounding-javascript-decimals).

Comment: Yes, I've corrected that. It's actually Math.round(1.53*20)/20.

But why would Math.round(1.53*20)/20 result in 1.55? Is there a better way to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.round() will return the nearest integer value as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

For your input `Math.round(1.53*20)/20` it will first calculate `1.53*20` answer is 30.6 Then your expression becomes

```
Math.round(30.6)/20
```

After that result of `Math.round(30.6)` is 31 (nearest integer)
Then your statement becomes `31/20` which is `1.55`